# ios - Disable Fabric Answers but keep Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have integrated Fabric Crashlytics and Answers into my app today.
According to German law the user must have the oppurtunity to disable the collection of analytics data.

I found this solution for Android: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36203869/4543961

Can anyone help me to find a similar solution for iOS? That will allow me to disable data collection but keep Crashlytics data collection.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. You can email into support(at)fabric(dot)io if you need Answers data collection turned off, include your app's bundle id.

Comment: Hi Mike, many thanks for you replay. I will send the mail.

Answer (score -4):

As of Fabric 1.7.2 you explicitly specify kits you want to use upon initialization of Fabric:

```
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class], [Answers class]]];
```

Thus if user disabled collection of analytics data - you may wish to not even initialize Answer kit.

Generally, just don't log any events and don't set any keys to Answers if user disabled data collection.

Comment: Answers is part of Crashlytics, so it will be activated when only adding Crashlytics.