# Disable Fabric Answers but keep Crashlytics

Tags: android, crashlytics

I would like to disable Fabric Answers and at the same time we still would like to use `Crashlytics`. We have already checked the previous queries, but could not find any definite answer for that.

> [Disable "Answers" but not "Crashlytics"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015788/disable-answers-but-not-crashlytics/36203869#36203869)

Even if we use the below core, it is still internally invoking the Answers.

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().build()).build());
```

Please let us know is there any other possible solutions?

Comment: If you write-in to support@fabric.io with your package name, we can go ahead and disable Answers from the backend.

Comment: Thanks for your update. We will contact you via mail. But I still hope, fabric team will consider providing some API's which can be Developer friendly in future releases.